# Generate special list from file in python

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a file like this :

```
one:two:three
four:five:six
seven:height:nine
```

And so on...
What I want is to parse it correctly to obtain this kind of variable:

```
myVar = [("one", "two", "three"), ("four", "five", "six"), ("seven", "height", "nine")]
```

Of course, the file isn't stopping at nine, there's a lot more of lines after that.

How can I do that in Python ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list compehension:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    myVar = [line.rstrip().split(':') for line in f]
```

If you need a list to tuples then pass `line.rstrip().split(':')` to `tuple()`:

```
tuple(line.rstrip().split(':'))
```

Comment: Worked great thanks !
I was going waaay to complicated for this.
Python is such a great language.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('your file') as f:
    myVar = [ tuple(a.split(':')) for a in f.read().split() ]

print myVar
```

Outputs

`[('one', 'two', 'three'), ('four', 'five', 'six'), ('seven', 'height', 'nine')]`

Answer (score 2):

The data you are dealing with, looks like delimiter separated. I would recommend using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader), like this

```
import csv
with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=':')
    print [row for row in reader]
```

You can convert this to a tuple, like this

```
    print [tuple(row) for row in reader]
```